# Using Linq for comparison of two Datatables

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, web-applications

I am developing a C# ASP.NET web application.  I have data being pulled from two databases.  One is the database that holds all of our actual data, the second is to be used so that users of the site can save "favorites" and easily find this data later.  The databases have the following columns:

Table1:

```
itemid, itemdept, itemdescription
```

Table2:

```
userid, itemid, itemdept, itemdescription
```

If the item is present in table2 (the user has already added it), I want to mark the item as removable if it comes up again in a search, and addable if it has is not yet in their favorites.

I've got data from both pulled into datatables so I can compare them, but I feel that using a nested foreach loops will be too tedious as the query is set to return a max of 300 results. Also to do that, I have to put a bool value in one of the tables to mark that it was found, so this seems messy.

I have read up a little on Linq, but can't find anything exactly like this scenario.  Could I use Linq to accomplish such a thing?  Below is an (admittedly crude) image of the search results page that may help get a better grasp on this.  In the real deal, the Add and Remove links will be imagebuttons.

[image: SiteLayout]

Comment: You can use LINQ but it's no different than using foreach loops. It won't simplify your code, it will only condense it, and in this case it may not do that because the delegate for comparing members will be ugly if written in method syntax. I would possibly use a mix of the two but there's no inherit advantage to using LINQ here.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Actually, it sounds like the inherent operation he wants to do is a `Join`, although it's a bit hard to tell from the question.  If so, the LINQ implementation will scale much better than two nested foreach loops.  You could implement it properly without LINQ, but it doesn't sound like the OP has done that.

Comment: @Servy a LINQ join has better performance than the nested for loop alternative? I would expect it to if it was LINQ to SQL and it became a join in the SQL query but if you're doing a join on two C# collections isn't it going to end up being very similar IL to code which uses a nested foreach loop (in both cases you're just excercising IEnumberable)? I'm pretty sure no LINQ to Objects query will have as good of performance as a standard for loop. Anyways, it doesn't mattter because he's comparing 300 records and my point is more that the LINQ code won't be much cleaner than iterative code here.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal : You're wrong. A Linq join is performed by creating a hashtable (`ILookup`) of the collection on one side of the join, then iterating the other side of the join and pulling matching keys in the hash table. It's pretty nifty and has considerably different performance characteristics to brute-force nested loops.

Comment: If you were to post some code, folks might be more tempted to solve this for you. Trying to write Linq on an imagined DataTable is tricky.

Comment: Basically, I just want to see if a user has "favorited" something yet and use that to determine what action they can do with that item in the search results.  If they have added it already, it will only allow them to remove it from their favorites from the search list.  If they have not, it will give them a link to add it.  The question is how would I join those two tables using Linq to do this?

Comment: @BigEMPin It sounds like you just want to put the favorite items into a `HashSet` and then, for each item, use `Contains` to determine which button to show, add or remove.

Comment: @spender that's interesting and something I'll have to look into when I get some free time. However, from what you've said the characteristics/type/amount of data in your collection will be the main thing determining the performance of a LINQ join. I'm still not  convinced that anything performs consistently better than standard for loops. All the other alternatives have infinitely more overhead due to the method calls necessary to enumerate the collection. Even in the join case you're still enumerating one collection and for the other you have the overhead of making the `ILookUp`.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: Creating a HashTable O(n), pulling keys from hashtable O(1), iterating other side O(n), therefore:  Linq join is O(n) (e.g. performance is proportional to number of items). Nested loops give O(n^2) (e.g. performance is proportional to the square of the number of items). I know which one I would prefer.

Comment: @spender then wouldn't that be 2(O(n)) for LINQ version? Also, O(n) only denotes the number operations, not the cost of each. Iterating an IEnumerable means at least n method calls. Iterating an array with a for loop means 0 method calls. Also, IEnumerable makes no guarantee that it does n operations. Assuming n is the number of items in a `List<T>` the underlying array could actually be of size 2n which depending on distribution could mean 2n operations. Obviously as you approach infinity the hashtable method has better performance but I don't know that the same is true for small collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to ever post the solution to this one, but I went with the HashSet setup, with one loop to compare.  Thank you everyone for your comments.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("isMarked", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(dc);
    string[] strArray = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<string>("itemid")).ToArray<string>();
    HashSet<string> hset = new HashSet<string>(strArray);
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
         if (hset.Contains(dr["itemid"].ToString().Trim()))
             dr[3] = 1;
         else
             dr[3] = 0;
    }
}
```